# Firebase-Admin, importing it to react application throws Module not found error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, firebase, firebase-admin

I'm developming simple React application which uses firebase admin.

I have generated react application by using [create react app](https://github.com/facebookincubator/create-react-app).

Then I have installed `firebase-admin` by using this npm command:

```
npm install firebase-admin --save
```

In my `index.js` I have added this import:

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
 import App from './App';
 import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

 import * as admin from 'firebase-admin'

 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
 registerServiceWorker();
```

When I launch with `npm start` command and open my page I get this error:

```
 Module not found: Can't resolve 'dns' in 'D:\path\to\my\project\node_modules\firebase-admin\node_modules\isemail\lib'
```

Why this is happening? Did I miss something?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Admin SDKs cannot be used in client-side environments. That includes web browsers. Admin SDKs can and should only be used in privileged server environments owned or managed by the developers of a Firebase app. You should use the [Firebase web SDK](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup) in your React app.

Comment: Gee, i don't see that detail in the docs. So if i were building some type of admin interface that allowed admins to view all users for example of my firebase instance, i would need to just make that a regular user within my app to grant browser-side control? Thus I'd have a collection of admins in my firebase instance? Admin SDK is for basically server-side only stuff (ie cloud functions)? Right?

Comment: Correct. You can host some privileged operations in a server (using admin SDK), and get your client-side app to contact the server when those operations are needed. You can use `admin.auth().verifyIdToken()` in the server to validate the requests.