# Firebase web client delete another user

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to set up some admin functionality which allows admin users to delete another user's authentication from the client. How can I do this?

From reading the docs, it seems it is not possible for a user to directly delete another user, and I will have to use something like the Admin SDK with cloud functions and maybe Firestore? I already have a users node in Firestore which contains their email and whether they are admin or a regular user.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use Admin SDK to delete a user, right.
But I don't think it can be done on client side.

[Firebase-Admin, importing it to react application throws Module not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582508/firebase-admin-importing-it-to-react-application-throws-module-not-found-error)

Below is backend approach:

You need the env variables:

```
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=xxx
FIRESTORE_DB_URL=xxx
```

`GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` - this is path to your service account key file.

```
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.applicationDefault(),
    databaseURL: process.env.FIRESTORE_DB_URL
});
```

The SDK automatically find your credentials file from the `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`.

And you can remove a user with his `uid`:

```
admin.auth().deleteUser(UID);
```

There is another way to initialize the admin sdk by using `refresh token`. 
https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup