# Issue running Snyk test against a fresh firebase project

Tags: firebase, snyk

I am trying to get started with Snyk on my existing Firebase project and running into this error when trying `snyk test`:

```
Dependency firebase-admin was not found in package-lock.json. Your package.json and package-lock.json are probably out of sync. Please run "npm install" and try again.
```

To make sure it's not a project issue, I created a fresh new Firebase project as of today (including functions and firestore add-ons) and right after initializing the project with default packages, the snyk fails with this same error.

FWIW, I have tried a fresh React-app installation as well and snyk runs test without issues there. This way I know it's not a snyk bad installation on my machine.

Any ideas where I should start to investigate. As clearing up the modules folder and re-runing npm install did not solve this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Firebase-Admin, importing it to react application throws Module not found error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44582508/firebase-admin-importing-it-to-react-application-throws-module-not-found-error)

Comment: don't think so. it is not related to my question at all. I just talks about how you can't use admin SDK on client. Issue I am having is tied to using Snyk inside a Firebase project for server side. Not client and no react here.

Comment: I've also looked at [this](https://support.snyk.io/hc/en-us/articles/360000912457-Out-of-sync-manifest-lockfile-in-the-project) and not too sure how it works, as it seems to just ignore the issue?